# What are the important texts of Shrouta Shaivism?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shaivism, resource, srikanthacharya

Srouta Shaiv Siddhant or Shrouta Shaivism is an Shaiva tradition. One important scripture i am aware is Srikantha's Bhashya on Brahmasutra (?) What are the important scriptures of Shrouta Shaivism apart from above scriptures?

please list all important Scriptures or texts of Śrikānth Siva Visistadvaita (Srouta Shaivism) school in descending order. If possible, provide online links of those scriptures with English translations which are out of copyright.

Namah Shivay

Comment: There r more than hundreds of books n Bhasyas on Shrouta Shaiv & all can't be mentioned here. Thus, go with d link.  http://web.archive.org/web/20060321211919/http://www.sroutasaivasiddhanta.org/nagalingasastry.htm  , check the header too, u wil find Nagalinga Sastry and Nilakantaradhya too. Just the names of d books r scattered so you have to take pains.  There is another site too http://sroutasaivasiddhanta.com/  check this. If you want more knowledge contact the site. Or in case you r not satisfied DM 'Ishaivite' or 'authentic_shaiv' pages on Insta. They will definetly help you with this.

Comment: @Chamunda das, Thanks man really appreciate

Comment: there is some brahmasutra commentry I have heard

Comment: @YOu will not know, Yeah Śrikānth bhasya on brhamasutra. Ig srouta Shaivism follow his school of siva visitadvaita